# for loop in c not outputting full array

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop

this is a simple question as i'm a new-comer to C. I am trying to write a script for outputting an array of the tangents of radians, of multiples of 5 from 0-60. but for some reason the for loop i have written only does this for the first element, and all other elements in the resulting array are 0.00, and it wont print them for each loop. i'm sure i've done something simple wrong with my loop, but i just can't see it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> 
float rad(float degree){
    return degree*M_PI/180;
}
int main(void){
    int i, j, dim=13;
    float Tan[dim];
    for(i=0; i<13; i++);{
        j+=5;
        Tan[i]=tan(rad(j));
        printf("%f\n", Tan[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Typo: `for(i=0; i<13; i++);{` -> `for(i=0; i<13; i++){` (you have a semi-colon before `{`.)

Comment: and `j` is uninitialized.

Comment: The problem would have been *very* easy to find using a debugger to step through the code. Please learn how to use a debugger, besides the compiler and a good editor it's the most valuable tool in your toolbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are **two** problems in your code :-

**1)** You haven't initialized `j` here `int i, j, dim=13;`

**2)** The way you used `for loop` is as per your requirement.Remove semicolon from the `for loop` statement.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, in your code

```
 j+=5;
```

is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as the intial value of `j` is indeterminate. To elaborate, `j` is an automatic local variable and not initialized explicitly, so the content is indeterminate.

Then, the for loop is also buggy.

```
 for(i=0; i<13; i++);
```

should be

```
for(i=0; i<13; i++)   // no ; here
```

to have a *meaningful* loop body to be executed.

Answer (score 3):

***1.*** You have inserted a semi-colon which you shouldn't have. Change your loop to :

```
for(i = 0; i < 13; i++){        //erase the ; after the parenthesis
    j+=5;
    Tan[i] = tan(rad(j));
    printf("%f\n", Tan[i]);
}
```

***2.*** Initialize variable `j` before trying to increase it with the statement `j+=5`, as this will lead to undefined behaviour.